# Going through JSON and drawing circles doesn't work with a Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API to try and loop through a JSON array, get a series of parameters and draw circles on a map according to those, but it's not working... at all...

The JS/jQuery code I'm using to do this is as follows:

```
    $.getJSON( "fetch-beacons.php", function( beacons ) {
    beacons.forEach(function(beacon) {
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                              strokeColor: '#add8e6',
                              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                              fillColor: '#add8e6',
                              fillOpacity: 0.35,
                              map: map,
                              center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(beacon.lat)), (Number(beacon.lng)),
                              radius: Number(beacon.radius)
                            });
             var contentString = '<div id="content">' + '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Beacon worth ' + beacon.creds + ' credits</h1>' + '</div>';

          var beaconinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: contentString
            });
            circle.addListener('click', function() {
                beaconinfowindow.open(map, circle);
            });

  });
});
```

fetch-beacons.php returns:

```
[{"id":"18","lat":"51.50561","lng":"-0.32425999999999994","creds":"1","radius":"465","uid":"1"},{"id":"20","lat":"51.505595655042406","lng":"-0.32432774740810555","creds":"1","radius":"275","uid":"1"}]
```

as type `application/JSON`. JS definitely receives it as such, because the network console shows it as doing so, as does a console writeline I put in.

However, for some reason, including the JavaScript above causes the map to simply disappear. Nothing in the console at all, it just disappears from the DOM. Which is odd.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised there are no errors in your console - perhaps you've disabled some error outputs in the browser, because that is invalid javascript

The problem is in this line

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(beacon.lat)), (Number(beacon.lng)),
```

should be

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(beacon.lat), Number(beacon.lng)),
```

---

Check the console output of

```
$.getJSON( "fetch-beacons.php", function( beacons ) {
    console.log(beacons);
});
```

is it what you expect?

Comment: any errors now though? it's valid javascript, so you may get some better idea - and by still not working do you mean the map still not showing at all with your code in place?

Comment: @somerandomteen - if you replace the $.getJSON as I've put in my question, does the output look correct?

Comment: that is indeed expected output.

Comment: got it working! Your center statement was correct, I was stupid and put it in the wrong place :) thank you so much!